# How to download XML from protected server to Android device?

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, authentication

I want to download an `XML` file from a web server, but the server requires a login. There is no custom login form, just a browser dialog, which `WebView` can't even show. I have tried to do some research, but I couldn't really find information about this type of login.

[image: screenshot of login dialog]

This screenshot shows the login dialog in the Opera browser. How can I log into the server and save the file that should then be shown?

Comment: Its going to depend on their code, it could do authentication in a dozen different ways, from HTTP Basic Auth, to a custom solution.  You'd need to reverse engineer their website to figure it out.  Generally solutions like this are not recommended and are very fragile, you should find another way to get that info instead, such as public API.

Comment: @GabeSechan Okay, thank you for your response. Is there some way to at least log in manually through a `WebView`?

Comment: You should be able to, as long as WebView isn't confused by the site.  Of course that login would only be good within that webview, it wouldn't automatically make any other request work.  Although if you were to scour the cookies and headers of the response, you might be able to find how they store the login token and use that in a future request.

Comment: As said by Gabe, this depends on the method of authentication used by the site. Using basic auth, you might be able to use `http://user:password@domain.com/` (note however that this might be visible in server logs!). Check with developer tools which response is given to the initial request. If manageable, programmatically handle the request and then show the result in the WebView (instead of letting the WebView handle the URL call).